# Property of recurrence defined by composition of polynomial with itself evaluated at 0

Tags: polynomials

I am trying to understand a part of  this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3930423/688539)

> $$
> a_1 = -a_2f'(\xi).$$
>
> i.e.
> $$
> -a_2 = (a_2-a_1)f'(\zeta)
> $$
> Putting this all together, $$
> a_1 = -a_2f'(\xi) = (a_2 - a_1)f'(\zeta),
> $$
> so either both $a_1$ and $a_2$ are zero, or you can divide through by whichever is non-zero to form an equation just in the other, and hence conclude that that must be zero.

I do not understand how the last equation was synthesized, combining the two equations, I got:

$$ a_1= -a_2 f'(\xi) = \left[(a_2 - a_1) f'( \zeta) \right] f'(\xi) $$

Did OP make a mistake or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

I cannot write comments but this would be my comment. I think you are correct and the final conclusion no longer holds because $f'(\xi)$ could be zero.

Actually, I do not even think that the final conclusion was right in the first place. For example, it does not cover the case $a_1=a_2$. Further, the proof does not even use the assumption that the coefficients are integers and this is a necessary assumption.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I will accept your answer by tomorrow if no better answers are submitted.